# Unable to Save Uploaded PDF Files in WordPress Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type in WordPress called "Samples" using the following code:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_samples_post_type() {
    // ...
}
add_action('init', 'custom_samples_post_type');
```

In this custom post type, I have added a PDF file upload field using the code below:

```
// Add PDF File Upload Field to Sample Post Type
function add_pdf_upload_field() {
    // ...
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_pdf_upload_field');
```

I have also created a function to render the PDF upload field and another function to save the uploaded PDF file to a specified directory:

```
function render_pdf_upload_field($post) {
    // ...
}

function save_pdf_upload_field($post_id) {
    // ...
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_pdf_upload_field');
```

The issue I am facing is that when I try to upload a PDF file using the "Upload PDF" field in the admin panel, the file does not get saved to the specified directory, and the file name is not stored in the WordPress database. Additionally, there are no error messages or indications of what might be causing this issue.

**full code:**

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_samples_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Samples',
        'singular_name' => 'Sample',
        'menu_name' => 'Samples',
        'all_items' => 'All Samples',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Sample',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Sample',
        'new_item' => 'New Sample',
        'view_item' => 'View Sample',
        'search_items' => 'Search Samples',
        'not_found' => 'No samples found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No samples found in Trash',
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => 'Samples',
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'A custom post type for uploading PDF samples.',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-document', // Change the menu icon as needed
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'samples'),
    );

    register_post_type('sample', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'custom_samples_post_type');

// Add PDF File Upload Field to Sample Post Type
function add_pdf_upload_field() {
    add_meta_box('pdf_upload', 'Upload PDF', 'render_pdf_upload_field', 'sample', 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_pdf_upload_field');

function render_pdf_upload_field($post) {
    $pdf_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pdf_url', true);
    ?>
    <label for="pdf_url">Upload PDF:</label>
    <input type="file" name="pdf_file" id="pdf_file" accept=".pdf" />
    <?php if ($pdf_url) : ?>
        <p>Current PDF: <a href="<?php echo esc_url($pdf_url); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html(basename($pdf_url)); ?></a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="pdf_url" id="pdf_url" value="<?php echo esc_url($pdf_url); ?>" />
    <?php
}

function save_pdf_upload_field($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if (isset($_FILES['pdf_file']) && !empty($_FILES['pdf_file']['name'])) {
        $pdf_file = $_FILES['pdf_file'];
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $pdf_dir = trailingslashit($upload_dir['path']) . 'samples/';
        $pdf_url = trailingslashit($upload_dir['url']) . 'samples/' . sanitize_file_name($pdf_file['name']);
        
        if (!file_exists($pdf_dir))
            wp_mkdir_p($pdf_dir);
        
        $pdf_path = trailingslashit($pdf_dir) . sanitize_file_name($pdf_file['name']);
        
        if (move_uploaded_file($pdf_file['tmp_name'], $pdf_path)) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'pdf_url', esc_url($pdf_url));
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_pdf_upload_field');
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem so that I can successfully save and retrieve PDF files associated with the "Samples" custom post type in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is not my favourite software package. Out of the box, it supresses all logging. Your first step is to, at least temporarily fix this. In wp_config.php, you need to set:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Find out where you log files are, run some control tests to see what background noise they generate, then test your upload.

You might also want to check the permissions and ownership on your WP upload dir and the subdir you are using for these files.

Do be aware that `sanitize_file_name()` does nothing to protect the system against LFI - and neither does your code.